# How to print a nested Hashmap in Java formatted

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I stuck on a problem printing a nested Hashmap formatted to the console in Java. My map structure is like this: `private static Map<String, Map<YearInterval, List<String>>> comicFilmMap = new HashMap<>();`

The output should look like this: `ComicName:
                                         Year 
                                             FilmTitle
                                             FilmTitle`

I tried a foreach but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest possible way is, you can use Map.Entry interface to iterate through your hashmap.
Below is the pseudocode for the same :

```
foreach(Entry entry: comicFileMap.entryset()){
  sysout(entry.getKey()); // this will be your comicName

  foreach(Entry entryChild: entry.getValue()){ //the getValue() will be again 
                                               //hashmap()
     sysout(entrychild.getkey());
     foreach(String str: entryChild.getValue()){//this loop will print list of 
                                                //string
       sysout(str); 
     }
  }
}
```

for more information you may use **https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-entry-interface-java-example/** link

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Got confused with the entryChilds type. Thanks a lot!